# How to hide the TIME value in record update?

Tags: yii2, timestamp, grid

I use Yii2 Framework,

I have this code for a column in the grid view:

```
                     [
                           'attribute' => 'ultimamodifica',
                           'value' => function ( $model ) {
                             $stampa= "";
                             if( $model->Utenteup_elenchi ){
                             $tip1= $model->Utenteup_elenchi;
                             //$tip1= ($tip1) ? User::findOne($tip1) : null;
                             //$tip1n= ($tip1) ? $tip1->id : "";
                             $stampa= $tip1;
                           }
                             return $model->ultimamodifica." utente ".$stampa;
                           },
                           'label' => 'Ultima modifica'],
```

Now, "ultimamodifica" is a column that contain the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and is typing like "TIMESTAMP".
This show me this value: "2021-02-22 11:58:14 utente 734".
I wish to show only the date and the user, so I want to hide the hour of update. The record will be "2021-02-22 utente 734". What I have to do for this?
Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Try `return Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->ultimamodifica) . ' utente ' . $stampa;`

Comment: TOP !! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [asDate()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asDate()-detail)

```
        [
           'attribute' => 'ultimamodifica',
           'value' => function ($model) {
               $stampa = '';
               if ($model->Utenteup_elenchi) {
                   $tip1 = $model->Utenteup_elenchi;
                   $stampa = $tip1;
               }
               return Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->ultimamodifica) . ' utente ' . $stampa;
           },
           'label' => 'Ultima modifica',
        ],
```